# Calculating Pitch Diameter of Threads

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Could someone please explain what the importance of "1.6166" is in this formula for calculating pitch diameter?

```
n = 1 / Nominal Pitch

D = Wire Center Diameter + Gage Wire Diameter

G = 0.57735 x Nominal Pitch

M = D - (1.6166 / n) + 3G

Pitch Diameter = M - ((3 + G) - (0.86603 / n))
```

Thank you

Comment: a bit more context on where these formulas came from will help you get a better answer here

Comment: Yeah I understand, Unfortuantely this is in some code I am working on, and this is the most information I have. Which is why its so confusing to me.

Comment: I am not sure if that number was being used as a sort of Bias, or if this is a standard constant used in calculating pitch diameter. I haven't been able to locate any information on where this number would have come from, I have tried searching quite a bit for it.

Comment: I figured it was a long shot to have someone be able to look at this and know what its for, unless they had already been involved in a project like this, but I decided to take the chance just to see if someone with more math understanding that myself would be able to figure out why that number would be of any value when calculating the pitch diameter of a threaded bolt using wire gauges.

Comment: $0.86603$ is $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ and $0.57735$ is $\frac{\sqrt 3}{3}$

Comment: What does double asterisk $**$ mean in this code?

Comment: I just bolded it, doesn't mean anything. Sorry.

Comment: @Raffaele Thanks for the reply. As you can see from this article https://www.prattandwhitney.com/Calibrating_Thread_Measuring_Wires_60_degree_threads_/ the 0.57735 value gives you the best wire size. Then you can see why 0.86603 is our other constant from this article https://littlemachineshop.com/images/gallery/instructions/ThreeWireMethod.pdf "The value 0.86603 is a constant
because we are only considering 60° threads. It encapsulates some
trigonometry involving the thread angle"

Comment: @JayMason, 1.6166 is probably related to tolerance.